# How can I rename my wallet in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I created a wallet with some incorrect parameters. Now I’ve added a new wallet. But I would like to rename the first wallet (to something like “wallet-test”) and give my new wallet the name I originally intended.

Answer (score 3):

You can rename the wallet directory name.

Example:

If I want to change the name of wallet `w1` to `w-1`

```
$ ls

anchors.dat   chainstate         indexes          peers.dat
banlist.json  debug.log          mempool.dat      settings.json
blocks        fee_estimates.dat  message_capture  wallets

$ cd wallets

$ ls

w1  w2

$ mv w1 w-1

$ ls

w-1  w2
```

You can restart `bitcoind` and confirm walletname with `getwalletinfo`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However, now I have a warning popup when I load Bitcoin Core. It states: Skipping -wallet path doesn't exist. Failed to load database path '[path]'. Path does not exist. Anyway to fix this? Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Remove wallet name from settings.json file in data directory